# How to access the weboperationContext headers in web api

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api

Can't able to access the header from webOperationContext in web API

Below code used to work with web services.
After migrating to web API it stoped working.

```
if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
{
  WebHeaderCollection headers = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
  headerval=headers.Get("Name");
}
```

WebOperationContext.Current always returns null.
please help..

Comment: There is a very big difference between WebServices and WebAPI. Old WebServices uses SOAP to transport data. WebAPI is all about HTTP. In terms of protocol there isn't much difference between a WebPage and WebAPI. So the chances are that this will not work. You can access you header through the `ApiController` base class.